# How to obtain an upper bound for $\sum_{x < X} \frac{\mu^2(x) \tau_k(x)}{\phi(x)}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\mu$ be the Mobius function, $\tau_k(x)$ the number of ways to write $x$ as a product of $k$ natural numbers and $\phi$ the Euler totient function. 
I would like to obtain an upper bound for 
$$
\sum_{x < X} \frac{\mu^2(x) \tau_k(x)}{\phi(x)}.
$$
In the paper I am reading, this is bounded by 
$$
\ll (\log X)^k
$$
without explanation. I would greatly appreciate any explanation. Thank you.

ps I can see that 
$$
\sum_{x< X} \frac{\mu^2(x)}{\phi(x)} \ll \log X
$$
so I think I just have to bound $\tau_k(x)$...

Comment: Could you tell us what R is?

Comment: typo, fixed. thanks

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle \sum_{x < X} \tau_2(x) \sim X \log X$.

Comment: Note that a plan of bounding $\tau_k(x)$ pointwise isn't going to give a good enough bound, because there's no pointwise bound of the form $\tau_k(x) \ll (\log x)^A$ (even for $k=2$).

Comment: @GregMartin that's good to know. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can obtain an explicit upper bound using the identity (where $p$ is restricted to primes)
$$\frac{n}{\phi(n)}=\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1+\frac{1}{p-1}\right)=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)}.$$
For $X\geq 1$, the above identity implies that
\begin{align*}\sum_{n\leq X}\frac{\tau_k(n)}{\phi(n)}
&=\sum_{n\leq X}\frac{\tau_k(n)}{n}\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)}\\
&=\sum_{d\leq X}\frac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)}
\sum_{m\leq X/d}\frac{\tau_k(dm)}{dm}\\
&\leq\sum_{d\leq X}\frac{\mu^2(d)\tau_k(d)}{d\phi(d)}
\sum_{m\leq X/d}\frac{\tau_k(m)}{m}\\
&<\left(\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{\mu^2(d)\tau_k(d)}{d\phi(d)}\right)
\left(\sum_{m\leq X}\frac{\tau_k(m)}{m}\right).
\end{align*}
On the right hand side,
\begin{align*}\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{\mu^2(d)\tau_k(d)}{d\phi(d)}
&=\prod_p\left(1+\frac{k}{p(p-1)}\right)\\
&\leq\prod_p\left(1+\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right)^k\\
&=\left(\prod_p\frac{1-p^{-6}}{(1-p^{-2})(1-p^{-3})}\right)^k\\
&=\left(\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}\right)^k,
\end{align*}
while it is straightforward that
$$\sum_{m\leq X}\frac{\tau_k(m)}{m}\leq
\left(\sum_{m\leq X}\frac{1}{m}\right)^k\leq (1+\log X)^k.$$
We conclude that
$$\sum_{n\leq X}\frac{\tau_k(n)}{\phi(n)}<\left(\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}\right)^k(1+\log X)^k.$$

**P.S.** Of course many other approaches are available and an asymptotic formula can also be proved. My goal was to give a fully explicit upper bound.

Comment: In the first identity are you assuming that $n$ is square-free?

Comment: @TakeshiGouda: I am not assuming that $n$ is square-free. The identity holds for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now

Answer (score 4):

One should always consider Rankin's method: for $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\sum_{n\le x} \frac{\mu^2(n)\tau_k(n)}{\phi(n)} \le \sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac{\mu^2(n)\tau_k(n)}{\phi(n)} \frac{x^\varepsilon}{n^\varepsilon} = x^\varepsilon \prod_p \bigg( 1 + \frac k{(p-1)p^\varepsilon} \bigg),
$$
assuming $\varepsilon$ is chosen so that the series/product converges. To show that the right-hand side is $\ll(\log x)^k$, it suffices to prove that
$$
\varepsilon \log x + \sum_p \log\bigg( 1 + \frac k{(p-1)p^\varepsilon} \bigg) \le k\log\log x+O(1).
$$
We note that
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon \log x + \sum_p \log\bigg( 1 + \frac k{(p-1)p^\varepsilon} \bigg) &\le \varepsilon \log x + \sum_p \frac k{(p-1)p^\varepsilon} \\
&\le \varepsilon \log x + \sum_p \frac k{p\cdot p^\varepsilon} + O\bigg( \sum_p \frac1{p^2\cdot p^\varepsilon} \bigg),
\end{align*}
and the sum in the error is $O(1)$ uniformly for $\varepsilon\ge0$; therefore it suffices to show that
$$
\varepsilon \log x + \sum_p \frac k{p\cdot p^\varepsilon} \le k\log\log x+O(1).
$$
If we choose for example $\varepsilon = 1/\log x$, the left-hand side is bounded above by
\begin{align*}
1 + &\sum_{p\le x} \frac kp + \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{x^{2^j} < p \le x^{2^{j+1}}} \frac k{p\cdot (x^{2^j})^{1/\log x}} \\
&= k\log\log x+O(1) + k\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{e^{2^j}} \sum_{x^{2^j} < p \le x^{2^{j+1}}} \frac1p \\
&= k\log\log x+O(1) + k\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{e^{2^j}} \bigg( \log\log x^{2^{j+1}} - \log \log x^{2^j} + O\bigg( \frac1{\log x^{2^j}} \bigg) \bigg) \\
&= k\log\log x+O(1) + k\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{e^{2^j}} \bigg( \log 2 + O\bigg( \frac1{2^j\log x} \bigg) \bigg) \\
&= k\log\log x+O(1)
\end{align*}
as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\tau_{k} (u)= \frac{k^{\omega(u)}}{k!}$ for squarefree $u$ with $\omega (u)\ge k$. Thus
$$\sum_{u<R} \frac{\mu (u)^{2} \tau_{k} (u)}{\phi (u)} \ll 
\sum_{u<R} \frac{\mu (u)^{2}k^{\omega(u)}}{\phi (u)}
< \prod_{p<R}(1+\frac{k}{\phi (p)})<\prod_{p<R}(1+\frac{1}{\phi (p)})^{k}=\frac{1}{\prod_{p<R}(1-\frac{1}{p})^{k}}$$
Then, by mertens' third theorem, we get
$$y_{max}\sum_{u<R} \frac{\mu (u)^{2} \tau_{k} (u)}{\phi (u)}
\ll y_{max} (logR)^{k}$$